# Proving that a function in $\mathbb{R^3}$ has a minimum on a set

Tags: real-analysis, lagrange-multiplier, stationary-point

Given $$f(x,y,z)=2x^2+y^2+z^2$$ I have to prove that f has a minimum on the set $$E=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R^3}: x^2yz=1\}.$$

$E$ is a closed set because of the fact that $g(x,y,z)=x^2yz$ is the preimage of the closed set $A=\{1\}$. But I cannot prove that it is bounded and use Weierstrass' theorem.

Is it right to use, instead, the multi variable Mean Value Theorem and show that there exists a point $\xi\in[x,y]\quad \forall x,y \in \mathbb{R^3}$ in which the function has a tangent plane?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$E$ is in fact not bounded. You should however be able to find $\tilde{E}\subset E$ such that $\tilde{E}$ is bounded and $f|_{E\setminus\tilde{E}}$ takes only "large" values.

Comment: E.g. by setting $z=1/x^2y$ and proving that $f(x,y,1/x^2y)$ grows arbitrarily large for large $x$ and $y$.

Comment: But once I find that $f$ tends to $\infty$ when $x$ and $y$ are large, how I prove that $f$ has a minimum?

Comment: Wolfram Alpha says that the Minimum is given by $$4$$

Comment: You can "cut off" the parts of the domain where you know that $f$ is large. This leaves you with some $\tilde{E}\subset E$ that you can choose to be compact, so $f$ must have a minimum there.